# IBM Domino Designer 9.0.1 Development

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus

I have just upgraded myself to new version and started development in 9.0.1 Revision 20131022.0932 ( release 9.0.1). I have couple of small queries.

1) Am I using the right version for development or need to upgrade by implementing patches etc?. This is stable for development?

2) Previously I was developing applications on 8.5.2 but my clients were on 8.5.x and 9.x.

This migration is safe for existing applications? no crashes? no code mismatch? Is their any guideline for developer? Co-Existence of clients is possible?

Please guide me and thanks in advance

Best Regards,
Qaiser

Comment: Make sure to apply latest fix packs (FP5 is the latest as of now) and more importantly make sure to upgrade the server to 9.0.1 with latest fixpacks.

Comment: Thanks @PerHenrikLausten for prompt response. We have already upgraded to server to FP 4 HF71. Fix patches are incremental on IBM Notes client 9.0.1 social edition or just apply FP5 directly and it's containing everything related to previous fix patches.

Comment: Just apply FP5 directly, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response.I really appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, upgrading to the latest Designer version is ideal, especially with (as Per recommends) the latest fix packs, as well as on the server.

For non-XPage design elements, there should be no incompatibilities with 8.5.x through 9.0.1, so you're good there.

If you do XPages intended to be rendered by older versions (either older servers or XPiNC in older clients), you could run into trouble there, using properties and controls that don't exist there. You can mitigate that a bit by going to the app's "Xsp Properties" in Designer and changing the "Minimum Supported Release". That won't help you avoid trouble with third-party plugins not installed everywhere, but it helps with the core runtime controls.